# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload MVC razor

Tags: jquery, json, razor, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been struggling to get this blueimp's file upload code to work correctly.   There are a lot of examples available, but none that uses MVC razor.

I have all the necessary css and js file included in my bundleconfig.cs and _layout shared view.

Has anyone done something similar to what I'm trying to accomplish?

[click here to view basic file upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html)

**View**

```
<!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" 
  action="/Account/UserProfilePic" id="ProfilePicForm" 
  name="ProfilePicForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
       <span>Select files...</span>
       <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
       <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
       </span>
     <br>
     <br>
       <!-- The global progress bar -->
       <div id="progress" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
       </div>
       <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
       <div id="files" class="files"></div>
</form>
<br>
```

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    var url = '/Account/UploadProfilePic';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UserProfilePic(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        string relativePath = @"~/Content/ProfilePics/" + guid + file.FileName;
        string path = Server.MapPath(relativePath);
        file.SaveAs(path);




        UserProfileViewModel model = new UserProfileViewModel();
        model.ProfilePicURL = relativePath;
        model.UserId = UserId;

        userRepository.UploadPic(relativePath, UserId);

        return Json(new { name = file.FileName });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a WebAPI MVC 5 controller to receive and process the uploaded file(s). One difference I see is I'm using the

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Files
```

to access the uploaded files. If there is only one file it is in index zero (0), e.g.,

```
var postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0]
```

I'm not quite clear what problems you are encountering from your question, but see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just add those two lines to the top of your razor view

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id of your form is "ProfilePicForm", and you are applying blueimp control to the upload control "fileupload", when you are supposed to apply the blueimp control (jquery) to the actual form itself and not the upload control. Your javascript should read:

```js
$('#ProfilePicForm').fileupload({
```